# Find all the possible combinations of allocations

Tags: python, pandas

I have groups of states and need to find all the possible combinations of allocations among the states. The number of the states in a group can be three, four, or five. For example, one group of the states includes NY, NJ, and CT. The total allocation is 100% for a group. The minimum allocation for each state is 10%. The incremental allocation is 10%. For this group of three, I need to generate the following:

```
NY     NJ     CT
10%    10%    80%
10%    20%    70%
10%    30%    60%
10%    40%    50%
10%    50%    40%
10%    60%    30%
10%    70%    20%
10%    80%    10%
20%    10%    70%
20%    20%    60%
20%    30%    50%
20%    40%    40%
20%    50%    30%
20%    60%    20%
20%    70%    10%
30%    10%    60%
30%    20%    50%
30%    30%    40%
30%    40%    30%
30%    50%    20%
30%    60%    10%
40%    10%    50%
40%    20%    40%
40%    30%    30%
40%    40%    20%
40%    50%    10%
50%    10%    40%
50%    20%    30%
50%    30%    20%
50%    40%    10%
60%    10%    30%
60%    20%    20%
60%    10%    10% 
70%    10%    20%
70%    20%    10%
80%    10%    10%
```

The number of the states in a group can be three, four, or five. The incremental allocation can also be 5% or 20%. The minimum allocation for each state is fixed as 10%. The minimum allocation % is not always the same as the incremental %. I tried to research online and haven't found anything tangible. Can you suggest some ideas on how to tackle this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack but produces the results.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

# global constant
INCR = 10

def sums(n,r):
    results = []
    c = {k: v for k, v in zip(range(r), [0]* r)}
    for tpl in combinations_with_replacement(range(r), n):
        d = c.copy()
        d.update(Counter(tpl))

        tpl = tuple(map(lambda x: x*INCR, d.values()))

        if all(tpl):
            results.append(tpl)
    return results


number_of_states = 3

data = sums(100//INCR,number_of_states)

pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[(80, 10, 10),
 (70, 20, 10),
 (70, 10, 20),
 (60, 30, 10),
 (60, 20, 20),
 (60, 10, 30),
 (50, 40, 10),
 (50, 30, 20),
 (50, 20, 30),
 (50, 10, 40),
 (40, 50, 10),
 (40, 40, 20),
 (40, 30, 30),
 (40, 20, 40),
 (40, 10, 50),
 (30, 60, 10),
 (30, 50, 20),
 (30, 40, 30),
 (30, 30, 40),
 (30, 20, 50),
 (30, 10, 60),
 (20, 70, 10),
 (20, 60, 20),
 (20, 50, 30),
 (20, 40, 40),
 (20, 30, 50),
 (20, 20, 60),
 (20, 10, 70),
 (10, 80, 10),
 (10, 70, 20),
 (10, 60, 30),
 (10, 50, 40),
 (10, 40, 50),
 (10, 30, 60),
 (10, 20, 70),
 (10, 10, 80)]
```

EDIT: to get 20% or %5 ranges, change the INCR to the percent desired.

Comment: Chris, thanks a lot. How do we change the incremental? The first 10 in your code indicates the minimum allocation, the second 10 in your code indicates the total allocation. If the incremental is 20 instead of 10, how would you do?

Comment: @Steve P explanation for getting 5% and 20% increments are given above.

Comment: Thanks Chris. My apology if it is not clear. I have tried to run with the two lines when you first posted. What I mean is that the minimum allocation needs to be fixed as 10% and then change the incremental to 20% or 5%. The two lines of codes in you edits will change both the the minimum allocation and the incremental value at the same time. The minimum allocation % is not always the same as the incremental %.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the data you have, you could check it like this by adding a new col

```
states = df.columns.to_list()#list_of_states_having distribution
df['sum'] = pd.Series(data = np.zeros((df.shape[0],1)))
for state in states:
  df['sum'] += df[state].apply(lambda x:np.int(x.split[:-1]))

df[df['sum']==100]
```

Comment: The above list is not what I can start with. I need to generate the above list based on the number of states and the incremental allocation.

Comment: is a list of states the same as the number of columns in the dataset and incremental values same as the minimum jump in any series?

Comment: Yes. For the above example, the list of states (3) is the same as the number of the columns (3). The columns are the states. The incremental value (10%) is the same for all three states.

Comment: if we are just checking the sum, we don't really need for incremental value here. for states being columns I have updated the code.